# Some strange error due to (probably) erraneous bash script

Tags: javascript, html, bash

I am facing some weird error. I am working on a querying engine interface where user is supposed to ask queries of the form **(Sub,Pred,Obj)** where Sub, Pred and Obj are resources (like in RDF). If a user wants to get matching Sub given Pred and Obj, then he will query **(?,Pred,Obj)**. So, ? indicates what user wants to get as output (we can have multiple ?).
Now on my web-page, I have tried all the 8 combinations but only 1 fails to display any output. This combination is **(?,Something,?)**. I have a bash script which on click of a button calls my C code (i.e. my querying Engine) with the correct query format. It stores the output of the query in a file. Now another command in the script runs another bash command which creates a web-page which contains each line of output in the form of an unordered list. Now when I pose the problematic query (i.e. **(?,Something,?)**), *the file contains the correct output, but the bash script doesn't create correct web-page.*

```sh
//BashScript (create_q_out_list.sh) to create the web-page from data
function createPage
{
    filename='temp'                                 
    outfile='q_out_list.html'   
    echo "<html>" > $outfile
    echo "<head>" >> $outfile
    echo "<title>" >> $outfile
    echo "List of Query Results" >> $outfile
    echo "</title>" >> $outfile
    echo "</head>" >> $outfile
    echo "<body>" >> $outfile
    echo "<ul>" >> $outfile
    IFS=$'\n'           
    while read line #Loop to go through each relation in the file
    do
        echo "<li>$line</li>" >> $outfile
        echo $line
    done < $filename
    echo "</ul>" >> $outfile
    echo "</body>" >> $outfile
    echo "</html>" >> $outfile
}

createPage $@
```

```
// JavaScript file that calls the above script and my querying engine to
// generate web-page and the file containing the output of the query respectively

var exec = require("child_process").exec;
function query(type, sub, pred, obj) {
  if (type === "Search")
    str = './search "<' + sub + "," + pred + "," + obj + '>" > temp';
  if (type === "Create")
    str = './create "<' + sub + "," + pred + "," + obj + '>" > temp';
  if (type === "Delete")
    str = './delete "<' + sub + "," + pred + "," + obj + '>" > temp';
  exec(str, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log("stdout:" + stdout);
    console.log("stderr:" + stderr);
    if (error != null) {
      console.log("exec error: " + error);
    }
  });
  exec("bash create_q_out_list.sh", function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log("stdout:" + stdout);
    console.log("stderr:" + stderr);
    if (error != null) {
      console.log("exec error: " + error);
    }
  });
}

module.exports.query = query;
```

In the above code, temp is the file which contains the output. Also, q_out_list.html is the web-page which should be produced as the output of running create_q_out_list.sh.
Now, both scripts are running well for all the combinations except the one I described above. But for that combination, querying engine still gives correct output i.e. temp file contains the correct output. But web-page generated doesn't have any info of the temp file.

Comment: Why not generate the HTML output in your JavaScript? There's no reason to use Bash here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JavaScript code does not wait for the first `exec` to finish before continuing with the `bash` invocation.

There are a couple of ways to fix this:

- Use `execSync` instead – this is easy, but will block the Node.js process while your subprocesses are executing
- Put the second `exec()` invocation within the first `exec()`'s callback (example 1 below)
- Use `async`/`await` and a promisified `exec()` – this is cleaner and nicer (example 2 below – with other modernizations too).

## Example 1

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
function query(type, sub, pred, obj) {
  if (type === "Search")
    str = './search "<' + sub + "," + pred + "," + obj + '>" > temp';
  else if (type === "Create")
    str = './create "<' + sub + "," + pred + "," + obj + '>" > temp';
  else if (type === "Delete")
    str = './delete "<' + sub + "," + pred + "," + obj + '>" > temp';
  else throw new Error("Invalid type");
  exec(str, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log("stdout:" + stdout);
    console.log("stderr:" + stderr);
    if (error != null) {
      console.log("exec error: " + error);
      return;
    }
    exec("bash create_q_out_list.sh", function(error, stdout, stderr) {
      console.log("stdout:" + stdout);
      console.log("stderr:" + stderr);
      if (error != null) {
        console.log("exec error: " + error);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

## Example 2

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var promisify = require('util').promisify;
var execP = promisify(exec);

const typeToBinary = {
  Search: './search',
  Create: './create',
  Delete: './delete',
};

async function query(type, sub, pred, obj) {
  const binary = typeToBinary[type];
  if (!binary) {
    throw new Error(`Invalid type ${type}`);
  }
  var command = `${binary} "<${sub},${pred},${obj}>" > temp`;
  const [stdout1, stderr1] = await execP(str);
  const [stdout2, stderr2] = await execP('bash create_q_out_list.sh');
  console.log(stdout1, stderr1, stdout2, stderr2);
}
```

Comment: Well, looking at it, you could probably populate the `q_out_list.html` directly from you javascript, rather than populating a `temp` file to be parsed by a synchronized Bash script.

Comment: Yes @LéaGris, I didn't think of that

Answer (score 0):

The `read` statement is missing a `-r` flag to prevent the expansion of its content.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# create_q_out_list.sh to create the web-page from data

function createPage
{
  filename='temp'
  outfile='q_out_list.html'

  li_results="$(
  # read without -r will mangle backslashes
  # see https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2162
    while read -r line || [[ ${line} ]]
    # Loop to go through each relation in the file
    # The || [[ ${line} ]] will allow entering the loop
    # even when the last line ends EOF, causing read to return false,
    # rather than with a newline character
    do
        echo "      <li>${line}</li>"
    done < "${filename}"
  )"

  cat >"${outfile}" <<EOF
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>List of Query Results</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
${li_results}
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
EOF
}

# Double quote array expansions to avoid re-splitting elements.
# See: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2068
createPage "$@"
```

Comment: In this code, you have closed <html> tag before <body> tag. Also,I treid this code, but still the problem persists.

Comment: I fixed the tag ordering. It would help diagnose your issue if you could provide the temp file content when it is not working

Comment: Please refer to this link: https://github.com/Sreyas-108/GDF/blob/master/src/QueryParser/temp

Comment: @VipinBaswan is it the temp file as it is when the html generation fails?

Comment: Yes. I have checked that as soon as this file is generated, I get an wrong HTML file

Comment: It tests  ok here, with:

`wget -qO temp https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sreyas-108/GDF/master/src/QueryParser/temp; bash create_q_out_list.sh; firefox q_out_list.html` 
Here you can see the content of [q_out_list.html (gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/leagris/97ade0ab98f4ab50a28f8cd46cb9e9bc)